# What's the difference between getModel and getDevice?

Tags: react-native

I am using the react-native-device-info package. DeviceInfo.getModel() and DeviceInfo.getDevice() return the same result. What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DeviceInfo.getModel()` method returns the model of the device. For example, "iPhone 11 Pro" or "Samsung Galaxy S10".

`DeviceInfo.getDevice()` method returns the device name. For example, "iPhone11,8" or "SM-G975F".

In some cases, the result of these two methods may be the same, for example, if the device manufacturer does not have a separate device name.

Comment: Is the device name something that can be changed by the user?

Comment: Yes
on an iPhone, you can change the device name in the Settings app, under General > About > Name. 
On an Android device, you can change the device name in the Settings app, under About phone > Device name.